# Add event handler to RadGrid programmatically

Tags: c#, telerik-grid, radgrid

I've created a RadGrid programmatically and tried to bind a BatchEditCommand to it, but it's not updating and disappear after clicking the save more than one. The BatchEditCommand is not fired at all, no knowing what event is firing, it's hard for me to debug, maybe I've missed out some important setting when creating RadGrid?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
{
    strategy = strategy + Convert.ToString(i);
    RadGrid RadGrid_Strategy = new RadGrid();
    RadGrid_Strategy.ID = strategy;
    RadGrid_Strategy.Skin = "Office2010Blue";
    RadGrid_Strategy.GridLines = System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridLines.Both;
    RadGrid_Strategy.DataSource = GetDataTableForStrategy(CY, i);
    RadGrid_Strategy.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.Top;
    RadGrid_Strategy.ShowHeader = false;
    RadGrid_Strategy.BatchEditCommand += new GridBatchEditEventHandler(RadGrid_BatchEditCommand);
    RadGrid_Strategy.MasterTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.Batch;
    RadGrid_Strategy.MasterTableView.BatchEditingSettings.EditType = GridBatchEditingType.Cell;
    RadGrid_Strategy.AllowAutomaticUpdates = true;
    RadGrid_Strategy.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowAddNewRecordButton = false;
    RadGrid_Strategy.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowSaveChangesButton = true;
    RadGrid_Strategy.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowCancelChangesButton = true;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(RadGrid_Strategy);
    RadGrid_Strategy.Rebind();
}
```

Where BatchEditCommand is not firing at all:

```
protected void RadGrid_BatchEditCommand(object sender, GridBatchEditingEventArgs e)
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event you're trying to call can only get fired if you make changes to your grid, then call any of these client-side functions from the RadGrid's BatchEditingManager:

- saveChanges(tableView)
- saveAllChanges()
- saveTableChanges(tableViews)

Check out [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/invoke-batcheditcommand#Gphr5dQboUqCdpvWOWVFIQ) on the Telerik forums for more info.